# htaccess maintenance page redirect results in "too many redirects" error

Tags: .htaccess

This is my code: why does this end in a infinite loop? (the idea was to forward all IP's except 1).

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=91.198.106.118
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/page\.html$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://domain.nl/i/page.html [R=307,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should remove `^` from request_uri

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is the same domain, you're redirecting everything to `/i/page.html` except `/page.html`. Strip out `/i/page.html` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in your .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !=91.198.106.118
RewriteRule ^(?!i/page\.html).*$ http://domain.nl/i/page.html [R=307,L,NC]
```